# Very complicated XQuery transformation

Tags: xquery

I have a very complex XQuery to write (at least by my standards).

Here is my input xml:

```
<testRequest>
    <request1>
       <Line>1</Line>
       <action>addtoName</action>
    </request1>
    <request2>
        <Line>2</Line>
        <action>addtoSpace</action>
    </request2>
    <request3>
         <Line>3<Line>
         <action>addtospace</action>
    </request3>
</testRequest>
```

In my output xml, the actions should be attached as attributes to the "request1" elements. So, based on the action element under a request1 element, the attribute for the request1 element should be one of the following:

```
if action = IgnoreCase(addtoName), the request1 element should be <request1 action=insertingname>
if action =  IgnoreCase(addtoSpace), the request1 element should be <request1 action=updatingspace>
```

Not only this, but also, I need to add an attribute to the  element, based on the action values underneath it. 
     So, I have to traverse each of the  elements under a  element and see if any of the  elements are equal to "addtospace" if yes, then I need to get the corresponding values of the  elements and make up the attribute for the  element. From the above xml, my attribute for the  element should be,

```
<testRequest lineFiller="Line Like 2_* AND Line Like 3_*>, where 2 and 3 are the respective line numbers.
```

and if there are no  elements with  element= addtoSpace, then the attribute for the  element should be "changed".

So, in summary, my transformed xml should look like this:

```
<testRequest lineFiller="Line Like 2_* AND Line Like 3_*>
    <request1 action=insertingname>
       <Line>1</Line>
       <action>addtoName</action>
    </request1>
    <request2 action=updatingspace>
        <Line>2</Line>
        <action>addtoSpace</action>
    </request2>
    <request3 action=updatingspace>
         <Line>3<Line>
         <action>addtospace</action>
    </request3>
</testRequest>
```

Any help to accomplish this humungous task will be greatly appreciated.

thanks!!!

Comment: ridermule, Such processing is much easier with XSLT. Are you interested in an XSLT solution?

Comment: Dimitre, I am actually pretty well versed with xslt... but unfortunately, last week a call was taken (not by me of course) that we should use only xqueries and not xslts. so, I am learning xqueries now.

Comment: ridermule, You have my sympathy. Maybe time to move to get another job? :)

Comment: i wish finding a new job was so easy in a small city! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define functions to generate the attributes that you need to add to your elements.

For adding to the "request" element, this should work:

```
declare function local:getaction($x) {
  if (lower-case($x/action) = "addtoname") then attribute action {"insertingspace"} else
  if (lower-case($x/action) = "addtospace") then attribute action {"updatingspace"} else
  ()
};
```

The linefiller attribute can be created similarly:

```
declare function local:getfiller($x) {
  attribute lineFiller {
      if ($x/*[lower-case(action) = "addtospace"]) then
          string-join(
          for $r in $x/*[lower-case(action) = "addtospace"]
            return concat("Line Like ",$r/Line,"_*")
          , " AND ")
      else "change"
      }
};
```

Then to put it all together, fun a simple for loop over your original document, adding in the attributes where needed:

```
let $doc:=<<your original document>>

return
<testRequest>
{ local:getfiller($doc) }
{ for $r in $doc/* return 
   element { name($r) } { 
    local:getaction($r),
    $r/* 
   }
}
</testRequest>
```

EDIT: enhanced getfiller function to return "change" if there are no actions

Comment: Hi evil otto,  First of all, thank you so much for the solution... it partially worked. The part that did not work was the lineFiller part. The function always seems to return an empty string. Also, if there are no <action> elements called "Addtospace", the funtion should return "Changed". I am stumped here right now. In any case thanks a lot for helping! you are really amazing!

Comment: I updated the `getfiller` function to put in the string if there are no actions.  I don't know why the function shouldn't be returning something; I copied it verbatim from my working test code.  What xquery engine are you using?

Comment: thank you again, evil otto! the solution actually worked... It was my fault yesterday... I did something stupid. I have one last request from you. If I want to modify the getfiller function to test for "addtospace" and also "addtoline" and do the same thing in both the cases, how do I do it? I tired to do this:  for $r in $x/*[lower-case(action) = "addtospace" or "addtoline"] and added the same thing in the if statement as well, but that did not work.

Comment: You have 2 choices:  `lower-case(action) = "addtospace" or lower-case(action) = "addtoline"` or `lower-case(action) = ("addtospace","addtoline")` -- the latter is more concise for this particular case, but the former is more general (separates out the OR subconditions)